# SharePoint PowerApps web part stuck on Fetching your app from mobile devices

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have Power Apps Canvas App.
It works anywhere from any device by direct link.
But when I add **Microsoft PowerApps(Preview)** webpart to SharePoint Online page and add this Power App - it works only on desktops.
It is not working on iPhones.
Is it possible to fix it?

It tried several SharePoint web parts - **Microsoft PowerApps(preview)** and **Enhanced PowerApps** - both not working on mobile devices.
[image]

Comment: And the same situation in Safari on Mac.